# App Crash after Facebook single signon

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook, ios-simulator, facebook-ios-sdk

I have implemented Facebook in my application, and noticed that I have some problems which I just can't figure out.

When Facebook signle-signon returns to my application after approval in Facebook.app, while running and debugging from XCode.. the app kind-of hang when resuming and after about 30 - 40 seconds it switches back to the page that requested facebook authentication. 
When I run the app stand-alone, without debugging in XCode the app crashes after 10 - 15 seconds. I pulled the crash log from the device, and this is the result: http://pastebin.com/MeT7Rt52

When I test this in the simulator, the same things happens... allthough it uses Safari instead. I do not believe that Facebook or Safari is or could be the source of the problem... since it cannot be.

I have searched and searched, but cannot find an answer to this problem.

Here is some of my code in my AooDelegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler(&uncaughtExceptionHandler);
    [FlurryAnalytics startSession:APP_FLURRY];

    [TestFlight takeOff:APP_TESTFLIGHT_KEY];
    facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:APP_FB_APP_ID andDelegate:self];

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    [self.window setBackgroundColor:[UIColor scrollViewTexturedBackgroundColor]];

    [...]

    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {
    return [facebook handleOpenURL:url]; 
}

- (void)fbDidLogin {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:[facebook accessToken] forKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
    [defaults setObject:[facebook expirationDate] forKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
    [defaults synchronize];
}
```

Comment: Are you testing in the iOS Simulator?

Comment: Yes, I have tested it there as well... forgot to add that to my post. Added it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I isolated the problem, and the answer to the question is something that I didn't expect it to be.
In my application, I use [TestFlightApp](https://testflightapp.com/)'s API. I initiate it when the application is launched, as I should... however, this is also the thing that prevents the app from returning to its previous state (as it seems).

I dissabled TestFligthApp and the application resumed as it should.

Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that this will solve the problem, but, can you try adding this method:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application 
            openURL:(NSURL *)url 
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication 
         annotation:(id)annotation  {
    return [facebook handleOpenURL:url];
}
```

The `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url` is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

the Facebook SDK is full bugs, what i use is Facebook + singleton, which combines the Facebook SDK into a singleton form that makes it way easier to work with.